# Multiheaded Monsters

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

Does anybody have a complete list of all multiheaded Monsters in DnD 3.5e?

We got a vague description of a "multiheaded beast" from a witness in our current campaign and I'm trying to figure out what we might be up against so I can prepare some spells.

Comment: In your campaign, what source books are being used?

Comment: I do not believe GM is restricted to set of source books

Comment: @jan.supol The question appears to be from a player's perspective.

Comment: we're relatively new to the game and just use the players handbook, the dm version and the monster manual

Comment: Mh, wait. You're telling me that your characters failed their knowledge rolls (or had no means of seeing the creature clearly enough to be entitled to one) and you're trying to read the books in order to optimize your strategy? Know that this is called metagaming and, while it is not a bad thig *per se*, it might be not what your DM expects from you. If he didn't tell you the monster name in the first place, you're basically cheating at the game. That said, this is a valid question, but please, ignore the knowledge that comes from this when planning your spells, or at least be very ashamed.

Comment: I will try to not do that anymore, thank you for the comment. I just find it fun to research these things and learn about the game. I do feel very ashamed about it now though.

Comment: Researching for fun and maybe for using the monster as transmutation fuel or for DMing is legit, just don't let that knowledge influence the choices of your character, if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a [hydra](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/hydra.htm) or a [chimera](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/chimera.htm).

It might also be an [ettin](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ettin.htm), but that would be more of a "two-headed giant" than a "multi-headed beast".

There are probably other multi-headed beasts in some of the weirder monster manuals (for example [Tiamat](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Tiamat), haha) but hydras are by far the most commonly known.

Hydras can be cold, fire, or "neutral".  When fighting a hydra, there's a complicated mechanism for chopping off its heads one-by-one, but I've found it more efficient to ignore the heads and just kill the body like a normal monster.